# How to use xmlrpc call on create category?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, xml-rpc

I just need to create category on remote site while create the category on current site. I used the  add_action('create_category', 'func_create_theme', 10, 2);  action hook.

The function func_create_theme() was executed through ajax call.

Thank you

```
 add_action('create_category', 'func_create_theme', 10, 2);

  function func_create_theme($catId){ 

      $category = get_category( $catId );

      $usr = 'upsol';
      $pwd = 'change2';

      $xmlrpc = 'http://localhost/~rocky/demo2/xmlrpc.php';
      $client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT($xmlrpc);

       $postcontent = array(
          'name' => $category->name,
          'taxonomy' => 'category', 
          'slug' => $category->slug
        );

       $res = $client -> query('wp.newTerm',1, $usr, $pwd, $postcontent);
       echo $postID =  $client->getResponse();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed following lines. May be the reason.

```
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php' );
```